# How to override attributes for javascript form widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting override 2 attributes from an existing javascript form widget on my page and am not quite sure how to go about it:

1. I want to redirect to a different URL upon form submission.
2. I need to push a data point to the end system with the id='prospects_referral_type' upon form submission

Here's the website where the form widget currently exists: https://jabzboxing.fitness/arcadia

This is the script for the widget:

```
<script src="https://widgets.healcode.com/javascripts/healcode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<healcode-widget data-type="prospects" data-widget-partner="object" data-widget-id="8423870a150" data-widget-version="0"></healcode-widget>
```

Here's a simplified version of the full implementation using Tamb's code, but still can't get the redirect to work:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script> 
$('healcode-widget').submit((e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  myAjaxPost();

window.location.replace("https://jabzboxing.fitness/thankyou");

})
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://widgets.healcode.com/javascripts/healcode.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<healcode-widget data-type="prospects" data-widget-partner="object" data-widget-id="8423870a150" data-widget-version="0"></healcode-widget>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the website takes you to a checkout process after your initial on page form.  Are you saying you want to bypass the cart and take them somewhere else?

Comment: Correct! I'm looking to redirect to a different Thank You page.

Comment: Do you want the routing(redirect) to be client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking for.

To update where the form gets posted:

```
jQuery('form[id^=prospect_form').attr('action', 'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

To add an additional field:

```
jQuery('form[id^=prospect_form').append('<input id="prospects_referral_type" type="hidden"/>')
```

Keep in mind, this code has to run after the form is loaded, but it doesn't have to be on submit.

Comment: I'll give this a shot! To have the code run after the form loads, can I put a setTimeout() call in there and what would that look like?

Comment: What is the code that loads the widget?  You may be able to use a callback.

Comment: Everything I have access to related to the widget is in the script from the originating post. Unfortunately, I can't modify the original .js file. From there it's being placed into the webpage using in-line HTML. I hope that's you were asking.

Comment: Hi Jennifer. I can't quite seem to get the code to work, and I'm pretty sure it's due to the fact that the script is loading at the same time as the form. Any thoughts?

Comment: What Tamb suggested should work because that script is running on submit of the form, so that ensures the form's existence.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a bunch of ways to do this:

**Clientside:**

Submit the form via AJAX (note: there are many ways to do this too).  Find out the oldest browser you're expected to support.  If jQuery is fine, use their ajax method and submit to the appropriate endpoint on form submission.

```
$('form').submit((e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  myAjaxPost();

//on the .success method of the ajax POST you can simply do one of these

// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";

})
```

**Server-Side:**

handle the post on the backend and simply reroute upon success.  This can take many forms, considering your backend could be .NET, Node, PHP.  Idk.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this method a try as well.

Comment: KMeyer25 any luck?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this method yet, as I'm currently working on another possibility that should also solve my data push issue. Not having much luck there, so I'm getting ready to explore this route next.

Comment: I've tried your script in the header, body, and footer of the page (individually), and still no luck. Any thoughts on what could be wrong? I appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you post the full implementation of the code? Are you getting console errors?

Comment: I added it to my original post.

Comment: I can't quite figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: I cant check the dev tools cuz I'm mobile rn. But make sure your jQuery selector is targeting the form element within the widget and not the widget itself.